# What are "disks" in this context of the structure of ZIP files?

Tags: file, zip, disk, file-structure

I'm currently working on a mini library for myself to compress and extract ZIP files. So far I don't have any major problems with [the documentation](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/digformatspecs/APPNOTE%2820120901%29_Version_6.3.3.txt), except that I don't get what "disks" are in a ZIP file and how to calculate the number of a disk:

> 4.3.16  End of central directory record:
>
> ```
> end of central dir signature    4 bytes  (0x06054b50)
>
> number of this disk             2 bytes   <= What does "disk" mean here?
>
> number of the disk with the
> start of the central directory  2 bytes   <= What does "disk" mean here?
>
> total number of entries in the
> central directory on this disk  2 bytes   <= What does "disk" mean here?
>
> total number of entries in
> the central directory           2 bytes
>
> size of the central directory   4 bytes
>
> offset of start of central
> directory with respect to
> the starting disk number        4 bytes   <= What does "disk" mean here?
>
> .ZIP file comment length        2 bytes
>
> .ZIP file comment       (variable size)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term [*disk*](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/5VpskBrnDJQl4s9g_z9uwVJdq1d2mHKxLsEJY2UuDkw=s658-no) refers to *floppy diskettes* in the context of splitting and spanning ZIP files (see chapter 8.0 of [the documentation](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/digformatspecs/APPNOTE%2820120901%29_Version_6.3.3.txt) that you provided; emphasis mine):

> 8.1.1 Spanning is the process of segmenting a ZIP file across 
>   multiple removable media. This support has typically only 
>   been provided for DOS formatted **floppy diskettes**.

Nowadays, implementations often no longer support splitting and spanning (e.g. [here](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) (see Limitations) or [here](https://github.com/yallie/as_zip) (see procedure `finish_zip()`)), as floppy disks or even compact disks went out of fashion. If you are fine with not supporting splitting and spanning (at first), you can set the values as follows:

```
number of this disk             2 bytes   <=  You only have one disk/file, so set it to 1.

number of the disk with the
start of the central directory  2 bytes   <=  You only have one disk/file, so set it to 1.

total number of entries in the
central directory on this disk  2 bytes   <=  Set it to the overall number of records.

offset of start of central
directory with respect to
the starting disk number        4 bytes   <=  Set this offset (in bytes) relative to
                                              the start of your archive.
```

If you want to support splitting or spanning, then you have to increase the disk count every time you start writing to a new disk/file. Reset the `total number of entries in the central directory on this disk` for each new disk/file. Calculate the offset relative to the start of the file.

Comment: "You only have one disk/file, so set it to 1." All implementations I've seen use 0 for the disk number. Not sure if it matters; the spec doesn't say if it's 0- or 1- indexed.

Comment: @ZachB: I took a look at one of the implementations that I have linked. At least that starts counting at 1. But maybe it's best to test whether 0 or 1 is correct.